# verilog code for bitlength operation

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

What is the Verilog code for bitlength operation. Example: If Y=45897, I need BitLength(Y)=16. verilog code for BitLength(Y) is ? Please help me to write this.

Comment: The bit-length of 45897 is 16 for unsigned and 17 for signed. You might be looking for $clog2().

Answer (score 2):

`$clog2(Y)` is the ceiling log2 function that returns the number of bits needed to hold the unsigned value Y.